# Mobx property returned as function instead of value

Tags: javascript, mobx

Full name getter returns as a function instead of value.

```
var person = mobx.observable({
    firstName: 'Matt',
    lastName: 'Ruby',
    age: 0,
    fullname: function() {
     return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    }
});

console.log(person.fullname) // returns a function instead "Matt Ruby"
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/srinivasdamam/t0y65zft/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic inference has been removed. You need to explicitly [**tag the function as a computed**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html#-computed-modifier):

```
var person = mobx.observable({
    firstName: 'Matt',
    lastName: 'Ruby',
    age: 0,
    fullname: mobx.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    })
});
```

Or:

```
var person = mobx.observable({
    firstName: 'Matt',
    lastName: 'Ruby',
    age: 0,
    get fullname() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
});
```